# What ports does Advantage Database Server need?

Tags: advantage-database-server

I have an application which uses ADS and I am attempting to deploy it in 
a Windows network environment with a rather restrictive firewall. I am 
having a problem configuring firewall ports appropriately.

ADS lives on \\server, and it's listening on port 1234. When \\client 
tries to connect to \\server\tables, I get Error 6420 (Discovery process 
failed). When \client tries to connect to \\server:1234\tables, I get error 
6097, bad IP address specified in the connection path. \\server is pingable from \\client, and I can telnet to \server:1234.

If I try to connect from a client machine inside the firewall, either 
connection path works fine.

It seems there must be something else I need to open in the firewall. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Aaron.

Edit: I should have specified that the firewall is open to \\server:1234 specifically for TCP traffic. Is UDP involved here in some way?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I had an outdated version of ADS. ADS does indeed use UDP by default, which is why traffic wasn't getting through. Newer versions (>= 8.1) can specify TCP instead.